# Problems when Drawing SVG with ScrollMagic on IE and EDGE

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, drawing, microsoft-edge, scrollmagic

I have some problems when drawing SVG with the library ScrollMagic: github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic

At this link http://goo.gl/avrW9r you can see the lines that was draw correcly in Google Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

My problem is only on Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge.

Have you got any ideas to resolve this problems?

You can download a example of my code here: https://goo.gl/qj5FQC

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Hey Roberto, did you ever find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

So this won't quite answer the ScrollMagic use case, but if anyone else happens to come across this and needs help with a custom JavaScript solution: my problem was that I was using *only* `document.documentElement.scrollTop` to determine the current scroll position.  You need to use `(document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop)` because Edge doesn't care about `document.documentElement` and instead looks for `document.body` while other browsers don't look for `document.body`.